# Changing html5 video source with preloading

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm setting up a video portfolio site to showcase different concepts for software devs, and there are often multiple versions of the same video.

I wrote the following javascript to change videos and it works fine locally, the problem is that once its hosted changing videos breaks the video player. I'm guessing the cause is because the new video is not loaded. Any ideas?

```
function switcher(wrapper, e, source, container, video){

//get current version and turn off its style
var off = document.getElementById(wrapper).getElementsByClassName("versionActive")[0];
off.className = "version";

//turn on the new button
e.className = "versionActive";

var videoSource = document.getElementById(source);
var videoContainer = document.getElementById(container);

lastPlayingVideo.currentTime = 0;
lastPlayingVideo.pause();
lastPlayingVideo = videoContainer;

videoSource.setAttribute('src', video);
videoContainer.load();
videoContainer.play();

}
```

The html for the video player looks like this:

```
<video id="container1" controls="" loop="" preload="auto" width="1280" height="720">
     <source id="video1" src="videos/Reminder.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
videoContainer.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
   videoContainer.play();
   videoContainer.removeEventListener('canplay');
});
videoSource.setAttribute('src', video);
videoContainer.load();
```

`canplay` is fired when the browser supposes you have received enough of the file and you can continue playing it considering your connection speed.

Comment: videoSource is the source tag nested in the video tag. I'll edit my post to show the html.

Comment: Thanks Lauromine, but I actually resolved the issue myself another way. I just listed all the videos out in html, and gave them all a display: none style except for the active video. The buttons switch videos by simply changing the style of the current video to display: none, and setting the style of the new video to display: auto.

Comment: Don't forget that by default, all your videos will start loading when the page has finished loading this can affect the speed at which the played video will download if the others are not finished loading, to avoid this you can add  `preload="none"` to your video tags, but it might recreate your issue ;)